# iOS AdMob full screen banner does not hide

Tags: ios, admob

I am using AdMob ad in my application. Ads are displayed correctly.

When i tap the ad, some of the ads are opening in full screen web page in my application.When i tap the **Done** button, it did not close the full screen ad and ad page just frozen.

AdMob API id invoke the

```
- (void)adViewWillDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)adView;
```

delegate method

but it never invoked the following delegate method.

```
- (void)adViewDidDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)adView;
```

I had to kill the application in iPad2.
I had to restart the iPhone 4s device (since i could not locate my application in the running application panel to kill).

Not sure what is wrong. I could not find any details in google.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Sasikumar JP

Comment: Are you sure you've set the rootViewController on your ad properly? Are you using the latest version of the AdMob SDK as well?

Comment: I was using 4.x sdk, it was causing this issue. i tried with the latest AdMob SDK, it solved the problem. Thanks for your update